# Junit - Null Pointer Exception with @Before

Tags: junit, nullpointerexception

I just started learning Junit and I just got Null Pointer Exception in my first test.

If I read correctly `@Before` annotation means it will be called before each test but looks like it doesn't or something else is wrong with this code. In this code below I get Null Pointer in `myList.add()` line.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class StudentTest {
    private List<String> myList;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        myList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Test
    public void size(){
        myList.add("TEST");
        assertEquals(1, myList.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: It works in my IDE. You should just run it as JUnit Test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imports (jupiter) indicate you're using Junit5. 
In JUnit5 you have to use the `@BeforeEach` annotation to indicate steps that have to be execute before each test method.

The `@Before` annotation was used in JUnit4.

I haven't tested this, just read the documentation https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Comment: You are right, its working with @BeforeEach. Looks like I imported wrong JUnit. Thanks.